# Iterating over pgfkey list - macros inaccessible

Tags: pgfplots, expansion

I have to draw a number of annotated number lines such as this:

[image: annotated number line with arrows]

For this I adapt the `pgfplots` interface with a few extra keys.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    number line,
    xmin=-2,xmax=4,
    xlabel={$f'(x)$\\$f(x)$},
    xtick={-1,2},
    interval labels={-1.5/$+$/$\nearrow$,0.5/$-$/$\searrow$,3/$+$/$\nearrow$},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Nice and clean.  The trouble is, sometimes I want a number line like this:

[image: annotated number line with quarter circles]

The quarter circles come from the `manfnt` package.  But now my implementation of setting a key equal to a list and iterating over the list won't compile.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{primary}{blue!40!black}       % HTML{000066}
\tikzstyle{number line value}=[primary,above]
\tikzstyle{number line description}=[primary,below]
\tikzstyle{number line point description}=[number line description,yshift=-2.5em,text width=2cm,text centered,anchor=south]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle}}
\pgfplotsset{
    number line/.style={%
     axis x line=bottom,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.1,
        axis equal image,
        hide y axis,
        every axis x label/.append style={%
            anchor=west,
            align=left,
        },
    },
    interval labels/.style={
        after end axis/.prefix code={
            \edef\mylist{#1}
            \foreach \x/\val/\desc in \mylist {
                \ifx\val\desc
                    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw ({axis cs:\x,0}|-{axis description cs:1,0}) node[number line value] {\val};}
                \else
                    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw ({axis cs:\x,0}|-{axis description cs:1,0}) node[number line value] {\val} node[number line description] {\desc};}
                \fi
                \temp
            }
        }
    }
}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\newcommand{\nequartercircle}{\manquartercircle}
\newcommand{\nwquartercircle}{\manrotatedquartercircle}
\newcommand{\sequartercircle}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\nwquartercircle}}
\newcommand{\swquartercircle}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\nequartercircle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[number line,
        xmin=-2,xmax=4,
        xlabel={$f(x)$\\shape},
        xtick={-1,0.5,2},
        xticklabels={$-1$,$\frac12$,$2$},
        % interval labels={-1.50//NW,-0.25//NE,1.25//SW,3.00//SE} % works, but not the symbols I want
        % interval labels={-1.50//\nwquartercircle,-0.25//\nequartercircle,1.25//\swquartercircle,3.00//\sequartercircle} % doesn't work
        after end axis/.append code={
            \coordinate (BR) at (axis description cs:1,0) {};
            \draw ({axis cs:-1.50,0}|-BR) node [number line description] {\nwquartercircle};
            \draw ({axis cs:-0.25,0}|-BR) node [number line description] {\nequartercircle};
            \draw ({axis cs: 1.25,0}|-BR) node [number line description] {\swquartercircle};
            \draw ({axis cs: 3.00,0}|-BR) node [number line description] {\sequartercircle};    
        } % works, but not the desired interface
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am guessing it has to do with how the macros in the list are expanded(`\nearrow` is not a macro, it's a character control sequence defined with `\mathchardef`), but beyond that I cannot tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to expand too much: the problem is with `\rotatebox`, which is fragile.

Remove `\edef\mylist{#1}` and change `\foreach \x/\val/\desc in \mylist` into

```
\foreach \x/\val/\desc in {#1}
```

and then use

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\val}
```

and

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\desc}
```

instead of the simple `\val` and `\desc` when you do `\edef\temp{...}`

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{primary}{blue!40!black}       % HTML{000066}
\tikzstyle{number line value}=[primary,above]
\tikzstyle{number line description}=[primary,below]
\tikzstyle{number line point description}=[number line description,yshift=-2.5em,text width=2cm,text centered,anchor=south]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle}}
\pgfplotsset{
  number line/.style={%
    axis x line=bottom,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.1,
    axis equal image,
    hide y axis,
    every axis x label/.append style={%
      anchor=west,
      align=left,
    },
  },
  interval labels/.style={
    after end axis/.prefix code={
      \foreach \x/\val/\desc in {#1} {
        \ifx\val\desc
          \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand\draw ({axis cs:\x,0}|-{axis description cs:1,0}) 
            node[number line value] {\unexpanded\expandafter{\val}};%
          }
        \else
          \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand\draw ({axis cs:\x,0}|-{axis description cs:1,0}) 
            node[number line value] {\val} node[number line description] 
            {\unexpanded\expandafter{\desc}};%
          }
        \fi
        \temp
      }
    }
  }
}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\newcommand{\nequartercircle}{\manquartercircle}
\newcommand{\nwquartercircle}{\manrotatedquartercircle}
\newcommand{\sequartercircle}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\nwquartercircle}}
\newcommand{\swquartercircle}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\nequartercircle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  number line,
  xmin=-2,xmax=4,
  xlabel={$f(x)$\\shape},
  xtick={-1,0.5,2},
  xticklabels={$-1$,$\frac12$,$2$},
  interval labels={
    -1.50//\nwquartercircle,
    -0.25//\nequartercircle,
    1.25//\swquartercircle,
    3.00//\sequartercircle
  }
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I don't actually think the problem was with `\rotatebox`, since I was still getting an error when I replace all the `\xxquartercircle`s with `\manquartercircle` (still a macro).  Could you explain a little bit the `\unexpanded\expandafter` combination?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang `\unexpanded` causes the expansion of `\expandafter`, because it looks for an opening brace; `\expandafter` expands (once) `\val` (or `\desc`) and then `\unexpanded comes into action, blocking the expansion of all resulting tokens when in an `\edef`.